# How to handle authentication in micro services using azure Ad and .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, microservices

Net core with micro services architecture. I have web application and API 1 and API 2.I have registered 3 applications in azure AD for web, API1 and API2. Currently I am generating token in web app by expecting user name and password against API1. This flow is working fine. Now I have added one more API which is API2. Now I want to authenticate from API1 to API2 with user context. The code in API2 requires claims such as roles, username and groups etc. So I want to generate token in API1 for API2 with user context. I am not finding way to complete this. Can someone help me with proper approach to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Is it helpful? If yes, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

[image]

I notice that you have another post about OBO flow.

The `client_id` and `client_secret` should be from the Web API Gateway application.

You should [expose an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#add-a-scope) in your Protected API application (you can get the **Application ID URI** like this format `api://<application-client-id of Protected API application>` in this step) and add the permission in your Web API Gateway application.

And `scope` should be `api://<service_application_id of the Protected API application>/.default`.

Since the content above is not related to this post, I just mention it briefly. Hope it helps.