# How to make a call from microservice A to microservice B with azure ad

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microservices, resttemplate

I faced with one problem. I have frontend application that call my microservice A, and microservice A call throw http microservice B. I use AAD at all instances (at frontend configured MSAL, at microservices configured like at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide) ). So, problem is when Frontend retrieve token from ADD to call microservice A or microservice B directly everything is ok. But when I try to call from microservice A microservice B - 401.

I understand why this happened, I have a token only for call one of them, so if I understand problem correctly, I need new token for communication between A and B. I found info about On Behalf Of (OBO), also I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539909/authentication-with-azure-aad-oauth2-using-obo-flow-in-spring-boot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66656506/how-to-handle-authentication-in-micro-services-using-azure-ad-and-net-core). But at project we do not use the WebFlux and reactive Java. I will be gladfully for sample how to communicate between microservices throw RestTemple using OBO.